# Understanding C Pointers

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){


// char* is a pointer
    char str_a[20];
    char *pointer;
    char *pointer2;

    strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world\n");
    pointer = str_a;
    printf(pointer);

    pointer2 = pointer + 2;
    printf(pointer2);
    strcpy(pointer2, "y you guys!\n");
    printf(pointer);
}
```

Hi, I'm following a book and have come across an program explaining pointers which I am unable to understand. The book does not seem to mention why it is this way, which means that I have to consult elsewhere to get a better understanding. The above code generates the following output:

```
Hello, world! (pointer)
llo, world!   (pointer2)
Hey you guys! (pointer)
```

What I fail to understand is that the last change to the variable `pointer` is on line 8. Yet the value of `pointer` can clearly be seen to change in the last line of output.

I would expect the value of `pointer2` to be `He` rather than `llo, world!` on the second line of output. The only thing that I can think of - is that on line 14, when + 2 is specified, the first two bytes of pointer is chopped (or the remaining bytes are chopped off, and the first two bytes stay the same in `pointer`?)

But this cannot be the case - because when I add `printf(pointer)` below `pointer2 = pointer + 2` - the output is "Hello, world!" again rather than "He"

Comment: C pointers point to the *start* of something. That's really all there is to it.

Comment: Neither `pointer` nor `pointer2` are pointers in your code. Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: Please enable compiler warnings and deal with them all. My compilation generates **9** warnings - almost as many lines as your code.

Comment: Your "pointers'" type should read `char*`. Copy your code exactly so we can help.

Comment: This is a really, really well-documented topic on and off the internet. You should pick up a copy of K&R and have a thorough read through -- it's really a good beginner's guide all things aside.

Comment: Note that using `printf(pointer)` etc without an explicit format string is bad practice.  Use `printf("%s\n", pointer)` or similar with an explicit format string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all *pointer* and *pointer2* are not declared as pointers, there should be a '*' before those variables to declare them as pointers. Even if this is from the book, this is not correct.

> What I fail to understand is that the last change to the variable
>   pointer is on line 8. Yet the value of pointer can clearly be seen to
>   change in the last line of output.

Yes! That's the point of pointers! *pointer2* has the same address as *pointer* but plus 2 elements (remember an array variable contains the address of the first variable of that array) as assigned in "pointer2 = pointer + 2;" Therefore, the "strcpy(pointer2, "y you guys!\n");" instructions will begin to copy the characters *after* the "He" since *pointer2* points to the first 'l'.

Answer (score 1):

Now, strings in c are zero-byte (`\0`) terminated, so when you assign `str_a` to `pointer` and print `pointer` the printer will go from the first address `pointer` points to until the terminating `\0`, so it will print all of the text.

But when assigning `pointer2` the value of `pointer` plus 2, you make it point two addresses after where `pointer` point, and when printing it you start from the `l` of `Hello`, until the terminating `\0`.

And for the third one, you replace the content in the memory from where `pointer2` points with `"y you guys!\n"`, so the total string starting from two addresses (where `pointer` points) before would be `"Hey you guys!\n"`, leading to the result you got.

```
H e       l l o ,  w o r l d \n      // start from pointer
^ pointer

H e       l l o ,  w o r l d \n      // start from pointer2
^ pointer ^ pointer2

H e       y   y o u   g u y s ! \n   // start from pointer
^ pointer ^ pointer2
```

Comment: OK — my comment removed.  It's hard to inspect revision history in the app.

Comment: C strings are NOT "null terminated".  NULL is a pointer value.  C strings are terminated by a byte with the value zero, usually written as `'\0'`. In the ASCII character standard this zero-valued byte is called "NUL" (one "L"), but using this name is confusing for obvious reasons, "zero" or "zero byte" or similar is better.

Comment: @JohnHascall thanks a lot for the clarification! fixed.

Comment: @JohnHascall: Actually, both the C standard (which is not limited to ASCII) and ASCII itself describe it as the "null character", or the "terminating null character" when specifically talking about the last character of a string, so if we're talking about C, that's the correct term to use. For example, C11 7.1.1.1: "A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character." NUL is just the ASCII symbol for it.

Answer (score 1):

`pointer` and `pointer2` basically point to the same chunk of memory. That said, the initial state is like this:

```
p     p2
H  e  l  l  o  ,  w  o  r  l  d  \n  \0
```

Then you overwrite the chunk under `p2` and it becomes:

```
p     p2
H  e  y   y  o  u    g u y s \n \0
```

Hope these charts make sense. When you print out a pointer it will always reach to the end of the array, which is `\0`.

Comment: this explains the last output well

Comment: Good answer for the OP, but of course it is only valid for `char *` - and in particular, those of the C-string type. (Per "When you print out a pointer ...")

Answer (score 0):

In C, pointers to strings (or anything) point to the *start* of the string, not the end.

For strings, the end is identified by the presence of a null (`'\0'`) character.

So, if you have a pointer to a string, say, `*p` pointing to `"Hello"`, this is how the string is layed out in memory:

<*p points to 1000>

```
| 1000 | 1001 | 1002 | 1003 | 1004 | 1005 |
   H       e      l      l     o      \0
```

Now, if you add 2 to `p`, `p` now points to 1002:

```
| 1002 | 1003 | 1004 | 1005 |
    l      l     o      \0
```

So, obviously, accessing `p` as a string pointer will give you "llo".  If you want to make the string *end* prematurely, you should set the target character to be `'\0'`:

```
char mystr[10] = "Hello";
char *p = mystr;
*(p+2)='\0';
```

Hell, you don't even need a pointer to do that. You can just do `mystr[2] = '\0';`

Comment: Not NULL, NUL -- see my longer comment on the other answer.